# Windows GUI as well as console application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have an application that i want to be able to be run without arguments and a GUI or as a console application when there are arguments present.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc > 1)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    ...
    return app.exec();
}

else
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    ...
    return app.exec();
}
}
```

This works fine under linux, but windows doesn't allow me to do any console output. After searching about the issue i found hints to AttachConsole() and reopening the output, so i added:

```
FreeConsole();
AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
freopen("CON", "w", stderr);
freopen("CON", "r", stdin);
```

This works fine, except that after the application returns the commanline doesn't return to an "input state".
To clarify instead of this:

```
C:\Users\x>
hello world
C:\Users\x>
```

it's stuck like this:

```
C:\Users\x>
hello world
```

The application exits correctly, just cmd doesn't seem to know this.
So anybody can tell me what kind of cleanup i have to do there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the shell launches a console application from an interactive command line, it waits for the application to exit.  That's necessary, because it prevents the application and the shell from competing for access to the console's input and output.  This also means that the shell knows when to reprint the prompt.

When the shell launches a GUI application from an interactive command line, it doesn't wait.  In this case, there's no need, and it would be inconvenient for the user.  (It does wait when launching a GUI application from a batch file.)

(The user can override the default behaviour by using `start` with or without the `/wait` option.)

By using AttachConsole() you've subverted this mechanism, giving yourself access to the console while the shell believes nothing else is using it.  This creates an inherent race condition - your output might wind up before, after, or intermingled with the shell prompt or with the output of other shell commands the user might run.  (Also, if you wanted user input, there would be no reliable way to predict which input would go to the shell and which to your process.)  The shell has no way to detect this condition and does not even attempt to do so.

The bottom line is that, unfortunately, there is no good way for a single executable to be suitable for both console and GUI use.  Instead, create two executables, one for each scenario.  If disk space is a concern, it is reasonably easy to make one of the executables very small, doing nothing but calling upon the other one.  Better still, you can put the bulk of the application into a single DLL and have both executables load it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your application appears "stuck" is because it hasn't actually exited yet, it's still in the event loop that you started by calling `app.exec()`

The solution to your problem depends on whether you need signals and slots in your console version.

1. If you don't need signals/slots, don't call `app.exec();`, just return an exit code.
2. If you do need signals/slots, fire off a quit signal to your application to let it know that the loop should be exited.

Comment: Since it's a GUI application, the shell doesn't care whether or not it has exited.

Comment: It's not a problem with the loop, the application actually exits. The same behavior is the same without ever starting an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

<s>As a workaround i fixed it by writing the working directory as a prompt to stdout.</s>
A possible [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) would be writing the working directory as a prompt to stdout.

```
out << QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath()) + ">" << flush;
```

Comment: What if the user has set a different prompt?

Comment: Ok, next time i'll make sure to call it a kludge.
I just wanted to point out this **kludge** since there doesn't seem to be a real **solution**. If someone would look in here he might be more happy with a **kludge** than nothing, that's why i posted it.  
I didn't accept my own answer for the very reason someone could post a real **solution** or explanation why this isn't possible (more than 'doesn't work') so i could accept it.  
Apparently playing nice gets you a downvote...

Answer (score -1):

It does return to the input state, only CMD doesn't know that it's supposed to re-print the prompt - how would it know, since it didn't run a console application?

What you need to do, essentially, is to trick the user into believing it is in the input state. You can either send a CR to `cmd` to force it to re-print to command line, or you can sniff the prompt and generate one yourself.

Comment: Well it's in the input state, but cmd doesn't look like it.
i can enter stuff etc, but for a user it looks like the program would still run since the prompt line isn't there.

Comment: If by sending CR you mean '\r\n' that doesn't help.
Could you elaborate on your second option? How would i sniff it?

Comment: Read up on how cmd generates its prompt. You can do the same. Heck, you can run a dummy cmd temporarily just to capture its output: it'll be the prompt :)

Comment: A more complicated kludge than the one the OP posted, but still a kludge!  Since both the shell and the OPs program are printing to the console in parallel, there's an inherent race condition.  There's just no safe way to do this.